# Loading a Partial via Ajax in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having a problem getting the page to update.  I am completely lost and don't know where to start.  My form for does have a `:remote=>true`  The page initialy loads with a partial wrapped in a div tag called comments.  I don't know what to place in the controller or what file to create, or even how to create it, to update the partial when the user clicks submit on the form.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you give a bit more info. Please post the code for the form. Also  are you familiar with RJS ? The same controller of the view can respond to  format.js and you can java a [actionname].js.rjs file that is rendered when the call happens

Comment: I am trying to figure out .js.erb but I am not quite sure how to do it.  I believe .rjs was deprecated in 3.0 and in 3.1 it is removed.  I want to respond in the same controller but, I don't know how to reload the data in the .js.erb file.  I am using JQuery and I understand that you can use format.js{}, but I am unsure of what to put in it `format.js{ :render_partial=>"comments"}` but then I don't know how to get that into the div.

Comment: @daniel you can see the code at https://github.com/plowdawg/Click-N--Slide

Comment: You are not using 3.1, you are using 3.0.9, but you still can do the same flow on 3.1, just respond_to do |type| { type.html {....} type.js { render :action => "youraction.rjs"}

Comment: @daniel it is not good to use deprecated code even if it still does work.  I potentially want to bring this up to 3.1 I have sort of tried but it keeps giving me RJS errors that seem to be from Rails itself.  If you use deprecated code you introduce possible security risks and make it harder to maintain especially as 3.1 is already out.

Comment: What I am telling you is not deprecated, what is deprecated in 3.1 is prototype and it's helpers, you are confusing this with the .rjs extension. Just put JQuery code into "youraction.rjs" and it will work by default in 3.1.

Comment: @daniel I think I got it confused by a deprecation warning about debug_rjs in the compiler.

Comment: Ok just simply add a respond_to do |format| { format.js {} format.html{}} to the controller action of the view that has the remote form. The app will bust since it will try to render a file, see which file it tried to render, create the file and add your JQuery javascript there. Or tell rails which file to render using render :action => "whateverfile.js.erb"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Travis,

I'm not sure which action you're trying to perform  here exactly, so let's assume you want to `create` a new resource.

Let's assume your resource is called `Post`

If you used rails to generate your `PostController`, you'll have a method `create` in there.

It may look something like this:

```
def create
  @posts= Post.new(params[:post])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@post, :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post}
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The key part here is that you'll need a `format.js` in the `respond_to` block.

When you put a `:remote => true` flag on your forms or links, you're telling rails that you want to make the request via Ajax.  This results in a `data-remote` attribute being placed on your `form` or `a` element and that is in turn used to tell the unobtrusive Javascript to use Ajax to submit your request.

What you need to make sure is present on your end are the following:

In your controller, make sure there is a `format.js` response format listed in the `respond_to` block (see example above for `html` and `xml`.

Second, we're going to create a `create.js.erb` file under your `app/views/posts` folder.  By default, rails will look for a `action.format.erb` file that corresponds to your action and format.

In the `app/views/posts/create.js.erb` file, you can now place your response javascript that will update your HTML document accordingly.  If for example, you had a list of posts and you wanted to add a newly created one to the end of it, you  may have something like this:

`app/views/something/show.html.erb`

```
<h1>Posts</h1>
<div id="posts">
  <%= render @something.posts %>
</div>

<!-- here we will include the :remote => true option, which will add a data-remote attribute to our form -->
<%= form_for Post.new, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :text %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

`app/views/posts/create.js.erb`

```
// here we're taking our newly created post and appending it to the list shown above
$('#posts').append("<%= escape_javascript(render @post) %>");
```

Finally, let's assume our post partial is something like this

`app/views/posts/_post.html.erb`

```
<p class="post-text"><%= @post.text %></p>
```

I'm not sure what javascript framework you're using, but here I'm using jQuery. I believe if you're using rails 3.1, jQuery is the default framework used, otherwise you'd have to look at [jquery_ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs).

Hope this helps.

Comment: After a bit I finally got what I wanted based of your answer.